# Cribbage score for pair of cards not in a row

Tags: cribbage

If player A play a 6 and then player B play a 7 and finally player A play another 6, considering that each player put their cards in their own stack, would the two 6 will be considering as a pair?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  The two sixes would not be counted as a pair.  The pair needs to be with the last two cards played.

> Pair: For adding a card of the same rank as the card just played Peg 2

https://bicyclecards.com/how-to-play/cribbage/